# Trying to convert imagedata to an heightmap

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm just trying to convert imagedata to an heightmap, to show in on the canvas. But when i do this, a strange thing appears, for all the images I tested.

Here is my code :

```js
window.onload = function()
{
 var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 if(!canvas)
 {
  alert("Impossible de récupérer le canvas.");
  return;
 }
 
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 if(!context)
 {
  alert("Impossible de récupérer le contexte du canvas.");
  return;  
 }
 
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = "noise.png";
 
 var size = 250000;
 var data = new Float32Array(size);
 var pxlData = new Array(size); 

 for ( var i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {
        data[i] = 0
    }
 
 for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) 
 {
  pxlData[i] = new Array(4);
  pxlData[i][0] = 0;
  pxlData[i][1] = 0;
  pxlData[i][2] = 0;
 }
 
 img.onload = function() 
 {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
  var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 500);
 
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  var pix = imgd.data;

  var j=0;
  var x=0;
  var y=0;
  var i=0;
  
  for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += (4)) {
   var all = pix[i]+pix[i+1]+pix[i+2];
   
   pxlData[j][0] = pix[i];
   pxlData[j][1] = pix[i+1];
   pxlData[j][2] = pix[i+2];
   pxlData[j][3] = pix[i+3];
   
   data[j++] = all/3;
  }  
  
  var alpha;
  
  for(y = 0; y < 500; y++)
  {
   for(x = 0; x < 500; x++)
   {
    if(data[x * y] <= 100){
     context.fillStyle = "blue";
    }else if(data[x * y] >= 100){
     context.fillStyle = "green";
    }
    //context.fillStyle = 'rgba('+ data[x * y] +', '+ data[x * y] +', '+ data[x * y] +', 1)';
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    
    // context.fillStyle = 'rgba('+ pxlData[x * y][0] +', '+ pxlData[x * y][1] +', '+ pxlData[x * y][2] +', '+ pxlData[x * y][3] +')';
    // context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
   }
  }
 };
 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
   <title>Génération de terrain</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="game" width="500" height ="500">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les canvas.</canvas>
  </body>
 </html>
```

That's what it's looking like when i run it :

[canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxlej.png)

Comment: What effect are you attempting to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is how you index the pixels in the 32 bit float array.

You have `data[x * y]` that means the pixel at 0,0 will be at index `0 * 0 = 0`and pixel at 0,100 will also be at `0 * 100 = 0` and all other indexes will be wrong. To get the correct pixel address use `x + y * width` when indexing from an array where one item is a pixel. If indexing into pixel data 'imageData.data' each pixel is 4 items (r,g,b,a) so you would use `data[x * 4 + y * canvas.width * 4]` or more simply `imageData.data[x + y * canvas.width * 4]`

Looking at your code you have create some common mistakes that will make you code run very slow compared to what it could do. I have simplified your code. It does the same but without all the overhead. I have added comments, removing your code and suggesting alternative methods of doing the same.

The biggest change is the rendering green and blue loops. You where setting each pixel with `context.fillRect(x,y,1,1);` this is very very slow. Rather than draw a rectangle for each pixel use the imageData you got and fill the colour after you read the height then just put that data back onto the canvas. I used two typeArray views to set and read the data this also improved the performance.

```
// convert r,g,b,a to 32 bit colour using correct little or big endian
function create32Pixel(r, g, b, a){  // dont call this inside loops as very slow
    var endianConvert = new Uint8ClampedArray(4); // use to convert to correct endian 
    var endianConvert32 = new Uint32Array(endianConvert.buffer); 
    endianConvert[0] = r;
    endianConvert[1] = g;
    endianConvert[2] = b;
    endianConvert[3] = a;
    return endianConvert32[0];
}

window.onload = function()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    if(!canvas)
    {
        alert("Impossible de récupérer le canvas.");
        return;
    }

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if(!context)
    {
        alert("Impossible de récupérer le contexte du canvas.");
        return;     
    }

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "noise.png";

    var size = 250000;  
    // Do you really need floats?? 16 bit unsigned int  array can hold 255 * 3 and all javascript 
    // numbers are converted to 64 bit floats so you will not lose precision from original when manipulating the 16bit values.
    // following array is not needed.
    //var dataFloat = new Float32Array(size);
    // following array is not needed.
    //var pxlData = new Array(size);  // bad way to create an array
    //var pxlData = [];  // create empty array and push onto it.


    // can use dataFloat.fill()
    /*for ( var i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {
        dataFloat[i] = 0
    }*/
    //dataFloat.fill(0); // but not needed as array is zeroed when created (not from an existing buffer)

    // Very inefficient as you are creating a new array for every pixel. Use flat array instead. 
    /*for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        pxlData[i] = new Array(4);
        pxlData[i][0] = 0;
        pxlData[i][1] = 0;
        pxlData[i][2] = 0;
    }*/
    // should do 
    /*var i;
    while(i < size * 4){
        pxlData[i++] = 0;  // array grows as you increase i;
    }*/

    img.onload = function() 
    {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // don't need to clear
        // context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // make two views one 8bit and the other 32bit. Both point to the same data change one
        // changes the other
        var pixChannels = imgd.data;
        var pixels = new Uint32Array(pixChannels.buffer);

        var j,x,y,j;
        j = x = y = i = 0;


        // Create pixel colours. Need to ensure correct order as some systems
        // use little edian and others big endian
        // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for info.
        var green = create32Pixel(0,255,0,255);
        var blue = create32Pixel(0,0,255,255);


        // use j as 32bit pixel index and i as 8bit index
        // read the height and set pixel colour accordingly.
        while(j < pixels.length){
            var height = pixChannels[i++] + pixChannels[i++] + pixChannels[i++];
            if(height <= 300){  // no need to divide by 3 just test for 3 time 100
                pixels[j++] = blue;
            }else{
                pixels[j++] = green;
            }
            i++; // skip alpha channel
        }
        context.putImageData(imgd,0,0); // put pixels back to canvas.

    };



}
```